# Is it possible to filter AMIs in aws_ami by names that you don't want

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

We've been using Terraform to manage our infrastructure for a while, and I'm currently refactoring part of it.  We would like two Autoscaling Groups inside AWS, where one group runs the latest version of our AMIs, and the other group uses the previous version.  As such, I'm attempting to look up both AMIs.

Firstly, we look up the latest release.  This is how our current infrastructure works, and is fine:

```
data "aws_ami" "ami_latest" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["server-name-*"]
  }

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["self"]
}
```

I'd now like to go find our previous version.  I thought I'd be able to make use of the [`name_regex`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/ami.html#name_regex) option in Terraform, and do a negative lookahead for the name I've just returned in the first block, thus returning the *previous* latest release:

```
data "aws_ami" "ami_previous" {
  most_recent = true

  filter {
    name   = "name"
    values = ["server-name-*"]
  }

  #our AMIs have . in them, so I'm escaping for the regex:
  name_regex ="^(?!${replace(data.aws_ami.ami_latest.name, ".", "\\.")}).+"

  filter {
    name   = "virtualization-type"
    values = ["hvm"]
  }

  owners = ["self"]
}
```

However, this results in a crash:

> panic: regexp: Compile(`^(?!server-name-1234.1234.1234.1234).+`): error parsing regexp: invalid or unsupported Perl syntax: `(?!`

We're currently using Terraform 0.11.10.  Whilst we have plans to upgrade to 0.12+, there are a number of places in our scripts that will need to be updated to fix various breaking changes between the two.

Is there a way to filter out AMIs to get what I'm after in 0.11.10?  Is there a way to get the inbuilt `name` filter to do this?

Alternatively, does 0.12.6 have updated regex support? - I'm loath to fix all the issues in order to try out 0.12.6 just to find it still has the same issue.

---

An alternative approach would be to use the filters themselves - it seems if I filter the AMI list directly in the AWS console I can get what I need using two filters on the name: `server-name-*` and `!'server-name.123.123.123.123'`, where the second is the latest version.  This gives me back the information I need.  However, I cannot get this to work in the filter blocks in Terraform.  I've tried various combinations along the lines of:

```
filter {
  name   = "name"
  values = ["server-name-*", "!'${data.aws_ami.ami_latest.name}'"]
}
```

And trying other things such as using two filter blocks, putting the negated one first etc.  None of them result in an AMI being found - it seems like while the negated filters work on the console, they don't work through the APIs, so this too is a dead end.

Comment: On the question of regex support, Terraform is written in go and go doesn't support lookahead or lookbehind assertions in its built-in regexp library https://golang.org/pkg/regexp/syntax/ Unless 0.12 adds an external regexp library that does support lookahead assertions, the answer is going to be no.

Comment: @Ngenator Thanks - that's useful to know.

Comment: This regular expression is being parsed by the AWS provider rather than by Terraform Core anyway, so it's a matter of which regex implementation that provider is using rather than which Terraform version. Indeed though, the implementation of that particular data source argument hasn't changed significantly since it was added, and it is indeed using the RE2 regex engine. It's a bug that it crashed on a syntax error rather than returning a validation error, so it'd be great if you'd open an issue about that in [the AWS provider](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-aws).

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks, that makes sense.  I think our provider is probably a little outdated - haven't upgraded for the same reasons of breaking changes across our scripts.  I'll try to verify that the unsupported regex still throws the same error in the latest version before opening an issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a workaround that may work in our specific use case, at least temporarily.

Our version numbers are of the form `server-name-a.b.c.d` where `c` indicates the actual release number.  By finding that particular number from the latest release, subtracting one off it, and filtering by that, I can find the previous version:

```
name_regex ="^server-name-\\d+\\.\\d+\\.${element(split(".", data.aws_ami.ami_latest.name), 2) - 1}\\.\\d+$"
```

It doesn't feel particularly robust (and will fail if we skip a version for instance), so I'm still very much open to other solutions, but this unblocks me for now...

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this is nearly a year old.

A pattern that I use to address this issue is to add tags to the AMIs, and filter by the tags. This avoids relying upon version numbers, although they could be used to further expand this concept.

tags like:

- Product
- Component
- Version
- Environment

Where:

Product: widget1

Component: backend

Version: 1.2.3

Environment: production-blue or production-green

Good luck!